# mysqli nested select query

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables and need to join them.

Table 1 : `ticket`

```
ticket_id    topic_id
---------------------
0001      |   1
0002      |   3
```

Notes: `topic_id` in the table `ticket` store the greatest `sort` order. Below I explain what `sort` is like.

Table 2 : `help_topic`

```
topic_id   parent_id  sort   topic_name
---------------------------------------------
1        | 0         | 0    | request
2        | 1         | 1    | shipment
3        | 2         | 2    | problem
```

Notes: sort 0 = category

sort 1 = case_type

sort 2 = sub_case_type

if the ticket doesn't have case_type and sub_case_type, then leave the field empty

And I need to show it like this:

```
ticket_id  | category   | case_type   | sub_case_type
-----------------------------------------------------
0001       | request    |             |
0002       | request    | shipment    | problem
```

I have tried this query to get the topic:

```
SELECT ticket.ticket_id, 
       ticket.topic_id, 
       help_topic.topic_name 
FROM ticket 
INNER JOIN help_topic 
ON ticket.topic_id = help_topic.topic_id
```

I'm running 3 different queries just to get the topic category, case_type, and sub_case_type, and it gives me problem because I assume the first query is to get `sub_case_type` but not every `topic` has `case_type` and `sub_case_type`

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got some doubts about your DB design, because if you add a new row on `help_topic` table, you should change your SQL to get your results.
Or maybe SQL is not sufficient to give you the correct solution and you should use your programming language to obtain what you want at the presentation level, instead of at data level.

Anyway, this SQL will extract the data you need, but NOT as you expected. You will get something like this:

```
ticket_id  | ht_1       | ht_2        | ht_3
-----------------------------------------------------
0001       | request    |             |
0002       | problem    | shipment    | request
```

As you can see, topics are not aligned.
Anyway, this is the SQL, if this can help you:

```
SELECT T.ticket_id, 
       ticket.topic_id, 
       HT1.topic_name AS ht_1,
       HT2.topic_name AS ht_2,
       HT3.topic_name AS ht_3
FROM ticket T
LEFT JOIN help_topic HT1 
ON T = HT1.topic_id
LEFT JOIN help_topic HT2
ON HT1.parent_id = HT2.sort
LEFT JOIN help_topic HT3
ON HT2.parent_id = HT3.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select t.ticket_id ,if(sort = 0,"request","") as category from ticket as t 
join help_topic as h on t.ticket_id = h.topic_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.